# Priority Queue using array of linked list C++

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list, priority-queue

So I'm trying to create a priority queue using an array of linked lists in C++. I'm not finished but if I can fix the constructor I think I can do the rest on my own.
I have a data file, first line has the number of items in the file.
The next line thereafter will have a char and then the priority level starting from 0 to 9.
So I'm sorting the alphabet which has 26 letters (the items). Each letter is given a level of priority. 
Ex. Q 5 (the letter Q has the priority 5) 
When I run this, it says that the program stopped working and then it starts to look for a solution. Like an error for an infinity loop I think.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Queue
{
private:
    struct linkedList
    {
        char data;
        linkedList *next;
    };
    linkedList* PQ[10];

public:
    //bool empty;
    //bool empty(int priority);
    void add(char info, int lvl);
    //void remove();
    Queue();
};

int main()
{
    int size;
    char Info;
    int Lvl;
    Queue Q;
    ifstream dataIn;
    dataIn.open("charQueueInput.txt");
    if (dataIn.fail())
    {
        cout << "File does not exist." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    dataIn >> size;
    dataIn.get();
    cout << size;
    /*for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        dataIn >> Info;
        dataIn >> Lvl;
        dataIn.get();
        Q.add(Info, Lvl);
    }*/
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

Queue::Queue()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        PQ[i] = NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {       
        PQ[i]->next = PQ[i + 1];
    }
    PQ[9]->next = NULL;
}

void Queue::add(char info, int lvl)
{
    if (lvl == 0)
    {
        PQ[0]->data = info;
        linkedList *temp = new linkedList;
        temp->next = PQ[1];
        PQ[0]->next = temp;
    }
    else if (lvl == 1)
    {
        PQ[1]->data = info;
        linkedList *temp = new linkedList;
        temp->next = PQ[2];
        PQ[1]->next = temp;
    }
    else if (lvl == 2)
    {
        PQ[2]->data = info;
        linkedList *temp = new linkedList;
        temp->next = PQ[3];
        PQ[2]->next = temp;
    }
    else if (lvl == 3)
    {
        PQ[3]->data = info;
        linkedList *temp = new linkedList;
        temp->next = PQ[4];
        PQ[3]->next = temp;
    }
    else if (lvl == 4)
    {
        PQ[4]->data = info;
        linkedList *temp = new linkedList;
        temp->next = PQ[5];
        PQ[4]->next = temp;
    }
    else if (lvl == 5)
    {
        PQ[5]->data = info;
        linkedList *temp = new linkedList;
        temp->next = PQ[6];
        PQ[5]->next = temp;
    }
    else if (lvl == 6)
    {
        PQ[6]->data = info;
        linkedList *temp = new linkedList;
        temp->next = PQ[7];
        PQ[6]->next = temp;
    }
    else if (lvl == 7)
    {
        PQ[7]->data = info;
        linkedList *temp = new linkedList;
        temp->next = PQ[8];
        PQ[7]->next = temp;
    }
    else if (lvl == 8)
    {
        PQ[8]->data = info;
        linkedList *temp = new linkedList;
        temp->next = PQ[9];
        PQ[8]->next = temp;
    }
    else if (lvl == 9)
    {
        PQ[9]->data = info;
        linkedList *temp = new linkedList;
        temp->next = NULL;
        PQ[1]->next = temp;
    }
}
```

Here would be an example of the data file:

```
7
Q 5
W 3
T 0
Y 4
A 9
B 5
U 0
```

And you would read it as:

```
0: T -> U
1.  
2.
3. W
4. Y
5. Q -> B
6.
7.
8.
9. A
```

T, U, W, Y, Q, B, A

Comment: Program-stopped-working isn't an "infinity loop"; it is a *crash*. It means your program is invoking undefined behavior. In the case of a smattering of linked list code it is *highly* suspect you're utilizing a bogus pointer in one fashion or another. Ex: You have a loop in your constructor that fills your array with NULL pointers, then another immediately after that does this: `PQ[i]->next = PQ[i + 1]` I.e you're dereferencing NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you access PQ before allocating memory.

```
class Queue
{
private:
    struct linkedList
    {
        char data;
        linkedList *next;
    };
    linkedList* PQ[10];   // Allocates pointer only
```

The class only allocates pointers to linkenList but not any instances.

Later you have:

```
// In constructor
Queue::Queue()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        PQ[i] = NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {       
        PQ[i]->next = PQ[i + 1];   // PQ[i] is NULL so run time error
    }
```

and also later

```
void Queue::add(char info, int lvl)
{
    if (lvl == 0)
    {
        PQ[0]->data = info;   // Access to non-allocated element!
        linkedList *temp = new linkedList;
        temp->next = PQ[1];
```

where you access PQ[0]->data. But the element has not been allocated so you get a run time problem.

Instead of

```
if (lvl == 0)
{
    PQ[0]->data = info;
    linkedList *temp = new linkedList;
    temp->next = PQ[1];
    PQ[0]->next = temp;
}
```

you need something like:

```
if (lvl == 0)
{
    if (PQ[0] == nullptr)
    {
         PQ[0] = new linkedList;  // If head of queue is null, allocate
                                  // new element for head
         PQ[0]->next = nullptr;
    }


    linkedList *temp2 = PQ[0];
    while(temp2->next != nullptr)  // Search the linked list
    {                              // to find last element
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
    // Now temp2 points to the last element in the list

    temp2->next = new linkedList;   // Allocate new element and add it
                                    // to the list after temp2
                                    // to get a linked list

    temp2 = temp2->next;            // Make temp2 point to the new element
    temp2->next = nullptr;          // Remember to initialize next of new element

    temp2->data = info;             // Save info
}
```

And in the constructor:

```
Queue::Queue()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        PQ[i] = nullptr;   // Use nullptr instead of NULL
    }

// Remove this block
//        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)  
//        {       
//            PQ[i]->next = PQ[i + 1];
//        }
//        PQ[9]->next = NULL;
}
```

It is not the pointers in the array which shall be linked.

Each pointer is a pointer to the HEAD of a linked list, i.e. 10 independent linked lists. So don't link them.

And finally - use the array in the add() function! Don't do the big if-statement.

```
void Queue::add(char info, int lvl)   // Tip: Consider making lvl an unsigned int
{
    if ((lvl >= 10) || (lvl < 0)) return;  // Ignore if lvl is out of range

    if (PQ[lvl] == nullptr)   // <---- USE lvl to index array
    {
         PQ[lvl] = new linkedList;  // If head of queue is null, allocate
                                  // new element for head
         PQ[lvl]->next = nullptr;
    }


    linkedList *temp2 = PQ[lvl];
    while(temp2->next != nullptr)  // Search the linked list
    {                              // to find last element
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
    // Now temp2 points to the last element in the list

    temp2->next = new linkedList;   // Allocate new element and add it
                                    // to the list after temp2
                                    // to get a linked list

    temp2 = temp2->next;            // Make temp2 point to the new element
    temp2->next = nullptr;          // Remember to initialize next of new element

    temp2->data = info;             // Save info
}
```

BTW - remember to create a destructor which deletes all elements in the 10 linked lists.

Comment: I know it says to avoid saying thanks but I'm REALLY thankful! Thank you! I am newb and don't know what I'm doing. Well actually I have terrible memory and not much experience. Started like 3yrs ago. orz

Comment: Oh, the while loop for searching the linked list is suppose to be a
while(temp2->next != nullptr) right?

Comment: @Kairi - ups, sorry about the while-loop. You are correct. It shall be `while(temp2->next != nullptr)`  I have updated the answer accordingly. BTW - it is considered better to use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.